# How to convert Hibernate Result Object to String?

Tags: java, hibernate, orm, casting

I implemented a hibernate query and would like to assign the result to one of my class variables.

The problem is that the results of hibernate queries seem to be objects or something, as the syso of a result looks very strange:

```
[exercise.java.basics.storage.WarehouseProduct@77f6d2e3]
```

This is the method executing the query:

```
 public void updateStock() {

    Session session = getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession();

    Criteria criteriaNail = session.createCriteria( WarehouseProduct.class );
    criteriaNail.add( Restrictions.like( "productName", String.valueOf( Product.NAIL ) ) );
    List nailCountResult = criteriaNail.list();

    System.out.println( nailCountResult.toString() );

    }
```

The database has only 2 colums and the value I need is in the second.
What I would like to do is something like this:

```
this.nailCount  = nailCountResult.[XYZ --> Get the value from the second column];
```

Is something like this possible? How can I cast these result objects to something readable?

best regards
daZza

Comment: You need to read about `Object#toString()`.

Comment: Implement toString() method for WarehouseProduct class

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all I suggest to change the line to

```
 List<WarehouseProduct> nailCountResult = criteriaNail.list();
```

And now it is not a ResultSet, it's a list of `WarehouseProduct` Objects.

You can access each object with index.

You can loop over the result list and  see them like

```
 for( WarehouseProduct wp : nailCountResult )   {
   System.out.println( wp.nailCount);    
  }
```

As a side note, you are breaking encapsulation here. Please look in to it.

Comment: Well, I'll be damned. It works :) Thanks for your help and I'll look into encapsulation later.

Answer (score 0):

All you need to to is this

```
String value=nailCountResult.get(0).getXXXX();
```